# Using a Variable name within the Workbook command in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make the syntax Workbooks("Some_Name").Activate using variable workbook name such as,
var = 1260
name = "Report_" & var
So that i can use
Workbooks(name).activate

but this is not working for me. How can i use it in correct way to achieve this.

I need this as I have a set list through which i loop through to get the model numbers like {1260, 1760...} and i have same set of report file with names already in my hard disc as Report_1260, Report_1760 so I want to make the name as variable so that I can use it in a loop.

Comment: Your code should work. Are you sure that those Workbooks are open before you call Workbooks().Activate method?

Comment: Yes the workbook is already open as here is the screenshot of the code where the file gets open take data from one sheet then again tries to activate the workbook with this method but it does not work. here is what i tried Workbooks(FlName).Worksheets("RS Confirm").Activate shows subscript out of range

Comment: @Kirszu the worksheet name i was using had a space included hence was not working now its working fine.

Comment: Cool! Glad you solved this

Answer (score 1):

My logic works fine its just that when I typed in the sheet name that had a space included which i did not take hence the subscript out of range error. So dynamically one can use workbook name as variable..

```
Workbooks("Code_Activator").Worksheets("Activator").Activate
    FolderPath = Range("C7").Value & "\"
    FilePath3 = FolderPath & FlName
    Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open(FilePath3)

    'Parts Confirm Data
    Worksheets("Parts upload template").Activate
    Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks("Blank_Template").Worksheets("Parts").Activate
    Range("A1").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select

    'RS Confirm Data
    Workbooks(FlName).Worksheets("RS upload").Activate
    Worksheets("RS upload").Activate
```

Comment: Avoid selections and activations 'cause it bloats code and makes reader keep all those selections in memory. *Most* of the time it's unnecessary.